# How to redirect data to a particular page using url in c#?

Tags: c#, redirect, get

I am working on jQuery fileupload now here I am saving images once saved some data I need to post to my page

Here I have two applications (two separate applications) html.page to I am posting images to mvc upload controller and I had saved the image success fully

Now to get the respose data I need to redirect through url so I am redirecting through like this

```
 public void ReturnResult(string jsonObj)
       {

           var hostName = " http://localhost:8988/cors/postmessage.html?MyURL=";
           var s = jsonObj;
           var filterUrl = hostName + s;
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(filterUrl);

       }
```

Once redirection to this page how could I get those data?

And I don't have any idea is this redirecting the data or not how could could I know that
data is redirecting or not could u plz help me get the data

this is my

redirected to  this  page

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Plugin postMessage API</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    'use strict';

    var origin = /^http:\/\/example.org/,
//var origin = 'http://localhost:4071/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx',
    target = new RegExp('^(http(s)?:)?\\/\\/' + location.host + '\\/');
    alert(1);
    alert(origin);
$(window).on('message', function (e) {
    e = e.originalEvent;
    var s = e.data,
        xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr(),
        f;
    if (!origin.test(e.origin)) {
        throw new Error('Origin "' + e.origin + '" does not match ' + origin);
    }
    if (!target.test(e.data.url)) {
        throw new Error('Target "' + e.data.url + '" does not match ' + target);
    }
    $(xhr.upload).on('progress', function (ev) {
        ev = ev.originalEvent;
        e.source.postMessage({
            id: s.id,
            type: ev.type,
            timeStamp: ev.timeStamp,
            lengthComputable: ev.lengthComputable,
            loaded: ev.loaded,
            total: ev.total
        }, e.origin);
    });
    s.xhr = function () {
        return xhr;
    };
    if (!(s.data instanceof Blob)) {
        f = new FormData();
        $.each(s.data, function (i, v) {
            f.append(v.name, v.value);
        });
        s.data = f;
    }
    $.ajax(s).always(function (result, statusText, jqXHR) {
        if (!jqXHR.done) {
            jqXHR = result;
            result = null;
        }
        e.source.postMessage({
            id: s.id,
            status: jqXHR.status,
            statusText: statusText,
            result: result,
            headers: jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()
        }, e.origin);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will greately appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data from the query string returned from the controller in your HTML page then you can use this function.

```
function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
                return vars;
            }
```

you can get you values on page load like:

```
var MyURL= getUrlVars()['MyURL'];
```

Comment: i had tried no error and no response i dont know is data redirecting to it or not how could know is data redirecting or not thanks for my reply Gerry thanks alot

Comment: Please paste here the url after redirecting.It must contain the data.

Comment: sorry i didn't get where do i have to paste the url thnks for reply

Comment: I mean to say please copy the url you are getting after redirection from the browser and write it in your comment.So that i can check what does it returns.